# Problema com array ao buscar do firebase e apresentar no FlatList

Tags: lista, firebase, react-native, firebase-database, firestore

**Ao executar este código recupero normalmente o objeto em doc.data(), mas ao setar no array useState os não consegue renderizar. O que pode estar acontecendo?**

Este é o retorno do console.log(listOS).

> Array [   Object {
> "customer": "Cgcx",
> "dateTime": "24/05/2023 19:51:59",
> "fuel": "008",
> "kmDriven": "558",
> "license": "Ggxf",
> "mechanic": "Fydd",
> "os": "5545",
> "percentage": "8587",
> "status": null,
> "userEmail": "jayson.mareco@jevsoftwares.com.br",
> "valueOS": "8558",   },   Object {
> "customer": "Fgg",
> "dateTime": "21/05/2023 23:55:21",
> "fuel": null,
> "kmDriven": null,
> "license": null,
> "mechanic": "Cvvv",
> "os": "6805",
> "percentage": null,
> "status": null,
> "userEmail": "jayson.mareco@jevsoftwares.com.br",
> "valueOS": null,   }, ]

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useCallback } from "react";
import { FlatList, SafeAreaView, View, StyleSheet, Image } from "react-native";
import ItemList from './itemList.js';
import * as SQLite from 'expo-sqlite'
import { TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import * as Animatable from 'react-native-animatable';
import {database, getDocs, query, where, orderBy, limit, collection} from "../../firebase"


function openDatabase() {
    if (Platform.OS === "web") {
      return {
        transaction: () => {
          return {
            executeSql: () => {},
          };
        },
      };
    }
    return SQLite.openDatabase("os_register.db");
}

async function listOsFirebase(user) {
    console.log("entrei no async");
    const listOS = [];
    try {
        const queryParams = query(collection(database, "list_os"), where("userEmail","==",user.email)/*, orderBy("dateTime"), limit(30)*/);
        const queryResult = await getDocs(queryParams);
        //console.log(queryResult);
        queryResult.forEach((doc) => {
            console.log(doc.id," => ",doc.data());
            listOS.push(doc.data()); 
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.error("Erro ao buscar: ", e);
    }
    console.log(listOS);
    return listOS;
};

export default function List(props) {
    const user = props.route.params.providerData[0];
    const navigation    = useNavigation();
    const [os, setOS] = useState([]);
    const db = openDatabase();
    db.transaction((tx) => {
        tx.executeSql(
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tb_os ("
            +"os TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, "
            +"created_at TEXT, "
            +"updated_at TEXT, "
            +"mechanic TEXT, "
            +"customer TEXT, "
            +"status TEXT, "
            +"percentage TEXT, "
            +"license TEXT, "
            +"km_driven TEXT, "
            +"fuel TEXT, "
            +"value_os TEXT "
            +");",
            null,
            null,
            (txtObj, error) => console.log(error)
        );
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        /*setOS([{
            "customer": "Fgg",
            "dateTime": "21/05/2023 23:55:21",
            "fuel": null,
            "kmDriven": null,
            "license": null,
            "mechanic": "Cvvv",
            "os": "6805",
            "percentage": null,
            "status": null,
            "userEmail": "jayson.mareco@jevsoftwares.com.br",
            "valueOS": null,
        }]);*/
        setOS(listOsFirebase(user));
    }, []);
/*
    useEffect(() => {
            db.transaction((tx) => {
                console.log("teste");
                tx.executeSql(
                    'SELECT * FROM tb_os;',
                    null,
                    (txtObj, resultSet) => {
                        console.log(resultSet);
                        setOS(listOsFirebase(user));
                        //setOS(resultSet.rows._array)
                    },
                    (txtObj, error) => console.log(error)
                );
            }); 
    }, [os]);
*/
      return(
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
            <Animatable.View animation="fadeInUp" style={styles.containerForm}>
                <FlatList 
                    data={os}
                    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                    renderItem={
                        ({item: os}) => (
                        <ItemList
                            os = {os}
                        />
                    )}
                    ItemSeparatorComponent={ () => <Separator />}
                    />
                <TouchableOpacity
                    style={{alignSelf: 'flex-end'}}
                    onPress={ () => navigation.navigate("Register",{"new":true,"user": user})}>
                    <Image source={ require('../../assets/icons/icons8-add-new-100.png') }/>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </Animatable.View>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
}

const Separator = (() => <View style={styles.separator}></View>)

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#38a69d'
    },
    separator: {
        flex: 1,
        height: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#DDD'
    },
    containerForm: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        borderTopLeftRadius: 25,
        borderTopRightRadius: 25,
        paddingStart: '5%',
        paddingEnd: '5%'
    },
})
```

*Fixando os resultados mostram bem:*

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useCallback } from "react";
import { FlatList, SafeAreaView, View, StyleSheet, Image } from "react-native";
import ItemList from './itemList.js';
import * as SQLite from 'expo-sqlite'
import { TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import * as Animatable from 'react-native-animatable';
import {database, getDocs, query, where, orderBy, limit, collection} from "../../firebase"


function openDatabase() {
    if (Platform.OS === "web") {
      return {
        transaction: () => {
          return {
            executeSql: () => {},
          };
        },
      };
    }
    return SQLite.openDatabase("os_register.db");
}

async function listOsFirebase(user) {
    console.log("entrei no async");
    const listOS = [];
    try {
        const queryParams = query(collection(database, "list_os"), where("userEmail","==",user.email)/*, orderBy("dateTime"), limit(30)*/);
        const queryResult = await getDocs(queryParams);
        //console.log(queryResult);
        queryResult.forEach((doc) => {
            console.log(doc.id," => ",doc.data());
            listOS.push(doc.data()); 
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.error("Erro ao buscar: ", e);
    }
    console.log(listOS);
    return listOS;
};

export default function List(props) {
    const user = props.route.params.providerData[0];
    const navigation    = useNavigation();
    const [os, setOS] = useState([]);
    const db = openDatabase();
    db.transaction((tx) => {
        tx.executeSql(
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tb_os ("
            +"os TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, "
            +"created_at TEXT, "
            +"updated_at TEXT, "
            +"mechanic TEXT, "
            +"customer TEXT, "
            +"status TEXT, "
            +"percentage TEXT, "
            +"license TEXT, "
            +"km_driven TEXT, "
            +"fuel TEXT, "
            +"value_os TEXT "
            +");",
            null,
            null,
            (txtObj, error) => console.log(error)
        );
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        setOS([{
            "customer": "Fgg",
            "dateTime": "21/05/2023 23:55:21",
            "fuel": null,
            "kmDriven": null,
            "license": null,
            "mechanic": "Cvvv",
            "os": "6805",
            "percentage": null,
            "status": null,
            "userEmail": "jayson.mareco@jevsoftwares.com.br",
            "valueOS": null,
        },{
            "customer": "Fgg",
            "dateTime": "21/05/2023 23:55:21",
            "fuel": null,
            "kmDriven": null,
            "license": null,
            "mechanic": "Cvvv",
            "os": "6805",
            "percentage": null,
            "status": null,
            "userEmail": "jayson.mareco@jevsoftwares.com.br",
            "valueOS": null,
        }]);
        //setOS(listOsFirebase(user)._array);
    }, []);
/*
    useEffect(() => {
            db.transaction((tx) => {
                console.log("teste");
                tx.executeSql(
                    'SELECT * FROM tb_os;',
                    null,
                    (txtObj, resultSet) => {
                        console.log(resultSet);
                        setOS(listOsFirebase(user));
                        //setOS(resultSet.rows._array)
                    },
                    (txtObj, error) => console.log(error)
                );
            }); 
    }, [os]);
*/
      return(
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
            <Animatable.View animation="fadeInUp" style={styles.containerForm}>
                <FlatList 
                    data={os}
                    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                    renderItem={
                        ({item: os}) => (
                        <ItemList
                            os = {os}
                        />
                    )}
                    ItemSeparatorComponent={ () => <Separator />}
                    />
                <TouchableOpacity
                    style={{alignSelf: 'flex-end'}}
                    onPress={ () => navigation.navigate("Register",{"new":true,"user": user})}>
                    <Image source={ require('../../assets/icons/icons8-add-new-100.png') }/>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </Animatable.View>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
}

const Separator = (() => <View style={styles.separator}></View>)

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#38a69d'
    },
    separator: {
        flex: 1,
        height: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#DDD'
    },
    containerForm: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        borderTopLeftRadius: 25,
        borderTopRightRadius: 25,
        paddingStart: '5%',
        paddingEnd: '5%'
    },
})
```

[Tela renderizando](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlCqb.jpg)